# How set Session variables in ASP.NET MVC 3 with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session-variables

So this is the question: how set Session variables in ASP.NET MVC 3 with jQuery?
I'm trying to use `$.ajax` or `$.post` but the problem is that I don't really know what to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332082/storing-values-in-asp-net-session-using-jquery

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Description

Just post to a controller and set the Session variable there.

### Sample

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $.post('/SetSession/SetVariable', 
           { key : "TestKey", value : 'Test' }, function (data) 
    {
        alert("Success " + data.success);
    });
});
```

**Mvc Controller**

```
public class SetSessionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetVariable(string key, string value)
    {
        Session[key] = value;

        return this.Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

### More Information

- [Save and retrieve Session data via Ajax using JQuery in an MVC 3 application](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Save-and-retrieve-Session-data-via-Ajax-using-JQuery-in-an-MVC-3-application.aspx)

Comment: Is this good practice? set session values using ajax request?