# record post in asp.net mvc 3 and jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

Hi I'm quite new to ASP and jQuery and could do with some help. I want to use an Ajax request to record the number of times a post request is sent, but haven't got a clue where to start. I thought it might be something to do with an jQuery.ajaxSetup but am unsure.

If anyone could help or a least point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Do you want to record the AJAX requests for a single view or your entire site? How do you intend to exploit the results?

Comment: just for a single view and it being used so i can perform an action when i reached a certain number of requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the beforeSend callback:

```
var count = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        if (settings.type == 'POST') {
            count++;
        }

        // Allow only 3 POST AJAX requests for this page 
        // and if there are more abort them
        if (count > 3) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on the client side with a cookie.  Otherwise you could do this server side with a session variable.

There are examples of both on here.

[How set Session variables in ASP.NET MVC 3 with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711998/how-set-session-variables-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-jquery)