# asp.net mvc 3 ajax post requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, post

hi i'm creating an application that will track when a user send a post request. once it has the  certain number of post requests it will redirect to another page is. I know that i will need to make an ajax function and that it will have to be on a loop to keep checking if the post have arrived but sure how this is done.

if anyone can help with this or at least point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: just count each time that the function that have the ajax called is used and check how many have been used

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function to execute some function at regular intervals:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this will run every second
    if (user reached POST limit) {
        // redirect him somewhere
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
}, 1000);
```

or if you are tracking the number of POST requests as I [showed you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972410/29407):

```
var count = 0;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        if (settings.type == 'POST') {
            count++;
        }

        // Allow only 3 POST AJAX requests for this page 
        // and if there are more abort them
        if (count > 3) {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is logging HTTP posts as they enter the web server you can do the following:

1 Check cookies to see if this is a repeat request If cookie meets your
   criteria, then redirect to different page. You might want to clear or
   reset the cookie at that time, as I suspect you might want to log at
   that entry point as well 
 2 Log the action

This does not need to be an Ajax request but it can be. To the web server, a request is a request.